# What did Anna tell Mademoiselle at the end of the Martyrs (2008)?

Tags: martyrs

At the end of [Martyrs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1029234/) (2008), Mademoiselle (Catherine Bégin) asks torture victim Anna (Morjana Alaoui) whether she has or has not witnessed Otherworld, and the answer is enough to make a 70-something, devoted, calm, focused, cold blood, cruel and emotionless person shoot herself in the head.

Any idea what she said?